# RXJS imports performance

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is there any best practice when importing?

Is one way better than the other?

```js
import { mergeMap, merge, withLatestFrom, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

//or

import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators/mergeMap';
import { merge } from 'rxjs/operators/merge';
import { withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators/withLatestFrom';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
```

Comment: This has been discussed here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3018. The recommended way is importing from `rxjs/operators` but if you want treeshaking to work properly you'll need some additional settings. Also see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#build-and-treeshaking

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600-alpha1-2018-01-12 in the newest release the recommended way will be the first, see the list of breaking changes